# How to point file to new physical location in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I moved a file to a new physical location. Now Xcode 4 marks the file reference with red text. Back in Xcode 3, I could right click > get info > and point the reference to the new physical location. What happened to this feature in Xcode 4?

*Aside: I was forced to upgrade to Xcode 4 because I couldn't figure out how to get the iOS 5 SDK on Xcode 3.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the file inspector. Choose View > Utilities > Show File Inspector to show the file inspector. The Identity and Type section at the top of the file inspector should let you change the file's location.

[image]